# Правильно ли решена задача?

Tags: c++

**Задача:**
В каждую крайнюю клетку квадратной доски поставили по фишке. Могло ли оказаться, что выставлено ровно k фишек? (Например, если доска 2 x 2, то выставлено 4 фишки, а если 6 x 6 - то 20).
**Решение:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main() {
   int k,x;
   cin >> k;
   if(k%4==0) {
       cout << "YES";
   } else {
       cout << "NO";
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

**Разбор задачи:**
В данной задаче фишки расставлены по периметру клетчатой квадратной доски. Зная формулу для нахождения периметра клетчатой доски: P = a x 4 - 4, где P - периметр; a - сторона квадрата, выразим а. Таким оразом, в задаче нужно, проверить делится ли введённое число P на 4. Также нужно отдельно рассмотреть случаи когда введённое число P равно 0 и 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, фигура из одной клетки представляет квадрат. Поэтому вы должны отдельно рассмотреть случаи с 0 и 1.
Также не имеет смысла использовать переменную знакового типа `int` для ввода количества.

Например, программа может выглядеть следующим образом

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the number of chips: ";

    unsigned int n = 0;
    std::cin >> n;

    bool square = ( n == 1 ) || (  n != 0 && n % 4 == 0 );

    if ( square )
    {        
        std::cout << "the number of the exposed chips correcponds to a square" << std::endl;
    }        
    else
    {        
        std::cout << "the number of the exposed chips does not correcpond to a square" << std::endl;
    }        

    std::system( "pause" );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем. При вводе нуля ответ будет "да", при вводе -4 (и остальных меньше нуля) тоже "да". Остальные случаи перекрыты.

Нужно добавить проверку на k>0 в условие.